# angularjs $resource class-level callbacks, or post-processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have a `$resource` whose API will always return some data that needs to be cleaned up before going into the presentation layer. Specifically, it's .NET returning Date objects in the lovely `'/Date(...)/'` format.

I don't want to have to write a callback every time I call `.query()` or `.get()`.  Is there some way to extend the resource with a callback that gets called upon REST methods that update the instance's properties, or by adding some sort of `$watch` that gets fired when the date property changes? Basically something that will happen for every instance of this `$resource`.

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Participant', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        var res = $resource('api/url/participants/:id', { id: '@id' });

        // This obviously doesn't work, but something kinda like this?
        res.prototype.$watch(this.FieldName, function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (needsCleaning(newVal.fieldName) {
                this.FieldName = cleanupField(newVal);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: can u try this.
`var participant = $resource('api/url/participants/:id', { id: '@id' });
 var commonCallback = function(){
 // inside this callback, participant is the populated model,
 // you can use participant object to do your formatting logic.
 // Then, if you would like to save the participant object do
 //participant.$save(); Please not the $ prefixed method names that becomes available to your resources instances.
 }
 
 res.query(commonCallback)
 or 
 res.get({..}, commonCallback)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah-ha, I found a way around it and will leave it here. In version 1.1.2 they added support for passing all the `$http.config` options to a `$resource`. Naturally, the CDN I'm using doesn't have a recent enough version of angular-resource.js, but switching CDNs solved that.

I just used the `transformResponse` option to modify the data as it comes back.

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Participant', ['$resource', '$http', function ($resource, $http) {
        var res = $resource('api/url/participants/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
                function (data, headersGetter) {
                    data.FieldName = yourDateParsingFunction(data.FieldName);

                    return data;
                }
            ])
        }
    });
```

I'm just adding my transformer on to `$httpProvider`'s transformResponse, which will do all the deserialization, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I like the `$http.defaults.transformResponse.concat` part.

Comment: Please note: you can't use AJAX request inside `transformResponse` to modify fields of `data` object

Comment: I had to add a return statement at the end of the factory function to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to do this is to overwrite the existing `$resource` methods you want to do post-processing on with your own. See the code and comments below for an example.

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Participant', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        var res = $resource('api/url/participants/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            // create aliases for query and get to be used later
            _query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            _get:   { method: 'GET' }
        });

        // redefine the query method
        res.query = function() {
            // call the original query method via the _query alias, chaining $then to facilitate
            // processing the data
            res._query.apply(null, arguments).$then(function(res) {
                var data = res.data;
                // do any processing you need to do with data here
                return data;
            });
        };

        // redefine the  method
        res.get = function() {
            // call the original get method via the _get alias, chaining $then to facilitate
            // processing the data
            res._get.apply(null, arguments).$then(function(res) {
                var data = res.data;
                // do any processing you need to do with data here
                return data;
            });
        };

        return res;
    });
```

You'd use it the same way you're currently using `Participant` in your code, via `Participant.query()` or `Participant.get()`. The data you return in the chained $then handler will be used to resolve the promise returned by `$resource`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not 100% sure, but I think `transformResponse` might be the easier way to go.

Comment: @c0bra, Intelekshual's way is useful when you need to access variables that are not accessible in `transformResponse`

Comment: Another advantage of this solution is we can reuse default methods from $resources to create our custom methods, and then transform responses easily

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was by adding a service to the module:

```
angular.module('keeniolab', ['ngResource']).
factory('KeenIO',function ($resource) {
    // factory implementation
}).service('KeenModel', function (KeenIO) {
    var KeenSession = function () {
        this.data = {};
    };

    KeenSession.prototype.fetch = function (query) {
        var self = this;

        KeenIO.get(query, function (result) {
            self.data = result;
        });
    };

    return new KeenSession();
});
```

Now you can simply monitor the collection:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    return KeenModel.data;
},
function (value) {
    // code here
});
```

[Keen.IO Resource Factory with Service Model](https://gist.github.com/webhat/5721162)